# "To clock in", what does this produce? "A clock-in"?

Tags: terminology

During a discussion, which was conducted in Norwegian, we came across the need to record the fact that the user clocks in or out when arriving or leaving work.

"To clock in" is a good description of the action the user performs, but the record in the database that the user clocked in, what do we call this?

A clock-in?

Is there a better word for this factual entry?

"His clock-in was 08:15"

Note that we're not looking for a description of what the user did, "He clocked in at 08:15" is quite good enough, but the record of him doing so, that's what we're struggling with a name for.

Comment: *In-time* (against *out-time* )?

Comment: Entry time, exit time!

Comment: I would say 'his clock-in time was 05.59'.

Comment: Also, "clock-in" seems to be okay. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-44182

Comment: @WS2 Please read the last para again. I think the OP wants a field-name for it.

Comment: @Kris I did read it before I posted my comment. I would use a noun phrase 'clock-in time'. I am not using it as a verb because that is what the OP says not to do.

Comment: @WS2 You ever did?

Comment: This is in fact a "field name" for a database, but it's also the name of this fact. In Norway there's some very different words used for this and they don't lend themselves to simply translating them to English. Specifically, to clock in is "å stemple inn", and "a clock-in" is "Innstempling", but "stemple" is "stamp", and that's not a word used for this concept at all. Unfortunately, some existing fields has already been given the name "Stamp", and this is what I want to correct.

Comment: in a database I might use "arrive" and "depart" for those fields. But you know there would be nothing from stopping me using clock-in and clock-out.

"His arrival was 08:15am"  "His departure was 05:15pm"

Answer (score 1):

"Time stamp" is the general term for whenever you do something that makes a record of the time.